# Make timer decrement actual seconds

Tags: c#, timer, win-universal-app

I have this code:

```
public void startSpinTimer()
{
  spinTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
  spinTimer.Tick += spinTimer_Tick;
  spinTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
  spinTimer.Start();
}

void spinTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
  spinTime--;
  spinnerTimer_txtBlock.Text = spinTime.ToString();
}
```

The spinTime variable is 6 in this instance. I'm trying to make the 6 represent hours so it'll be displayed as 06:00:00 and then every time the timer ticks it'll take a second away making the 06:00:00 change to 05:59:59 then 05:59:58 and so on..

I've tried to convert the spinTime to a `DateTime` variable however it doesn't work, it looks like I'm not going down the right path to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is `spinTime`? You should be able to subtract from a `TimeSpan`, something like `spinnerTimer_txtBlock.Text = Timespan.FromHours(6).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(spinTime)).ToString()`, and increment `spinTime` instead of decrement it (starting at zero).

Comment: spinTime is an `int` that stores 6 @RonBeyer

Comment: See my edit, increment it and use a timespan to determine the new time on each tick.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks, this worked perfectly! Can you add your comment as an answer please?

Comment: @RonBeyer Actually, its not ticking? It's calling the tick method every tick however isn't decrementing the time by 1 second :/ im confused.. it just sticks at 05:59:59

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that spinTime is TimeSpan type.
You can use this to decrease of a second.

```
            spinTime = spinTime.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Comment: The problems is that timer ticks are not precise, so if you just subtract one second each time you may be off by several minutes or more when it's done. Better to keep a starting point and compute the time difference each time.

Comment: How have you made your `int` (spinTime) have a `Subtract` method? O.o

Comment: @KTOV, he was assuming your `spinTime` is a `TimeSpan`. But you should look into extension methods.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using an integer, I would use a `DateTime` that stores the current time + 6 hours, and compute the difference between the current time and the "end" time:

```
// right before starting timer
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(6);

// in the `Tick` event:
spinnerTimer_txtBlock.Text = (endTime - DateTime.Now).ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a timer to "tick off seconds" is unreliable.  You can't guarantee that the tick will occur exactly every 1 second. Instead I suggest the following:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now; //On the start of the timer store the current time
TimeSpan spinTime = new TimeSpan (6,0,0); //Time to spin
```

On every tick evaluate the difference between the current time and the start time:

```
TimeSpan delta = DateTime.Now-start; //Time elapsed since start
TimeSpan timeRemaining = spinTime - delta; //Time remaining
```

This way you ensure that you're not depending on the timer to keep track of an accurate time.  Additionally, you can decrease the length of your tick to increase accuracy.